# x87 FPU and integer arithmetic?

Tags: x87

I'm trying to understand using the FPU for 64-bit integer arithmetic. I write this (ATT syntax):

```
fildq   A
fildq   B
faddp
fistpq  C
```

The result in C is A + B + 1. If I start with an "finit" instruction, it gives me the correct value A + B. I thought that the unwanted +1 was maybe because it was adding in a carry bit, but using gdb I see no difference at all in the FPU control registers when I use finit from when I don't -- in both cases the control register starts off as 0x27F, the tag register is 0xFFFF (= stack empty), and all the others (including the status register, where all the condition bits are located) are zero.

Using finit seems a bit of a blunt instrument here, and I'm also wondering where the extra +1 is coming from if I don't use it, given that all the FPU registers seem to have the same values in both cases. Can anyone shed any light on this for me?

Answer (score 0):

> […] I see no difference at all in the FPU control registers when I use finit from when I don't -- in both cases the control register starts off as 0x27F […]

Are you sure?
`finit` is supposed to load `0x37F`, one *additional* bit set in comparison to `0x27F`.
The difference is in the *precision control field*.
The default value uses 80‑bits whilst your observed value is using 64‑bits.

> The result in C is A + B + 1. […]
> Using finit seems a bit of a blunt instrument here, and I'm also wondering where the extra +1 is coming from if I don't use it, […]

With sufficiently *large* `A` and `B` you’re likely seeing a loss in precision from `fadd`.
Unmasking the precision exception will confirm this.
I think you were using the inline assembly capabilities of your favorite compiler.
This is certainly convenient if you don’t wanna bother about menial tasks, yet apparently your compiler’s run-time system loads `0x27F` at startup for compatibility considerations.
Study its manual (and possibly source code) for details.

Comment: No, I was writing directly in assembler (assembling a .s file). But you're right about finit -- 0x37F with, 0x27F without -- my mistake. I am assembling with this command: "gcc -g -o x.exe -nostartfiles -Wl,-estart -w x,s" and then stepping through and looking at A, B and C in memory with gdb. Note that I'm not using any external runtime package. I've no idea what might be responsible for messing with the control register.

Comment: @user1636349 `x.exe`, huh? On a Win64 target the x87 (as well as MMX and 3DNow!) instruction set extensions are deprecated. I mean, your program _does_ run, but I wouldn’t be suprised if your OS is messing with you. On a Linux and FreeBSD system I’m not experiencing any difficulties.

Comment: Win32 target, or I could just do 64-bit integer arithmetic using integer arithmetic instructions. I decided to try using the FPU as an alternative to add/adc sequences, but it looks like add/adc is easier.

Comment: Why would you think integer arithmetic were somehow better with x87, with the FPU? Do general-purpose integer arithmetic with the ALU. Utilize the FPU to _overcome_ magnitude restrictions _possibly_ to the _detriment_ of precision. Use arbitrary precision arithmetic libraries to overcome GPR’s magnitude restrictions _and_ maintain precision, yet not being fast. Each method has its advantages and disadvantages; pick the one that suits _your_ application. [PS: Considering OOE, you could theoretically use the FPU to _distribute_ workload if you’re using the ALU, too.]

Comment: You missed this bit at the top of my post: "I'm trying to understand using the FPU for 64-bit integer arithmetic." A sermon like this does not help me to understand the FPU's integer arithmetic capabilities at all.